# useSWR has infinite service call

Tags: reactjs, next.js, swr

I have a api that only uses POST, so i have to sent an ID to fetch, in this case event.

The problem is that my SWR is making infinite calls.

I have this component:

```
const EventDetail = ({ params }: { params: { id: string } }) => {
  const id: string = params.id;
  const [cookies] = useCookies(["token"]);

  const token = cookies.token;
  let formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("id", id);
  const dataToRequest = { token, formData };
  const { data, error, isLoading } = useSWR(
    [SERVICESADDR.EVENT, dataToRequest],
    fetcher,
  );
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
  console.log(data);

  return <div>{id}</div>;
};

export default EventDetail;
```

and my fetcher is:

```
export const fetcher = ([url, data]: [
  url: string,
  data: { token: string; formData?: FormData },
]) =>
  fetch(url, {
    method: "POST",
    body: data.formData,
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${data.token}`,
      "Accept-Language": "pt",
      Accept: "/*",
    },
  })
    .then((res) => res.text())
    .then((res) => res);
```

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the `key` (first argument of `useSWR`) is tied to the [cache key](https://swr.vercel.app/docs/arguments).
If any value in this array is updated, a new http request will be triggered.

In your example, the key is `[SERVICESADDR.EVENT, dataToRequest]` and `dataToRequest` object is recreated at each render, that's why you get an infinite service call.

You can pass the `token` and the `id` to key and create the `FormData` object in the `fetcher` function

```
const EventDetail = ({ params }: { params: { id: string } }) => {
  const id: string = params.id;
  const [cookies] = useCookies(["token"]);
  const token = cookies.token;
  const { data, error, isLoading } = useSWR(
    [SERVICESADDR.EVENT, token, id],
    fetcher,
  );

  return <div>{id}</div>;
};
```

```
export const fetcher = ([url, token, id]: [
  url: string,
  token: string,
  id: string
]) => {
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("id", id);

  return fetch(url, {
    method: "POST",
    body: formData,
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      "Accept-Language": "pt",
      Accept: "/*",
    },
  }).then((res) => res.text());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try turning the `FormData` object into a plain old JS object before using it as a value in the SWR key. It's unclear from [`useSWR`'s "Passing Objects" docs](https://swr.vercel.app/docs/arguments#passing-objects), but it might not be serializing it as expected and therefore seeing a new object on every render and always thinking the cache key has changed:

```js
const dataToRequest = { token, formData: Object.fromEntries(formData) };
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it didn't work. In network tab,request, it shows [object Object] and server returns error.